# Is there a way to group data based on a column that separates values with commas in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

Say there is dataframe A:

```
   A  B
1  1  gr1, gr2
2  3  class1, gr1
3  4  gr2
```

Is there a way to summarize data for each comma seperated letter in column B?
For example to get the mean of them like so:

```
   group   mean
1  gr1     2
2  gr2     2.5
3  class1  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can easily be done with the function `separate_rows()` from tidyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <-
  tibble(A = c(1, 3, 4),
         B = c("gr1, gr2", "class1, gr1", "gr2"))

dat %>%
  separate_rows(B, sep = ", ") %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(A))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
  B       mean
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 class1   3  
2 gr1      2  
3 gr2      2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

An option in `base R` with `strsplit` on the column 'B' to create a `list`, then using `tapply`, get the `mean` of the `rep`licated 'A' values where the group is `unlist`ed split values

```
lst1 <- with(df1, strsplit(B, ",\\s+"))
tapply(rep(df1$A, lengths(lst1)), unlist(lst1), FUN = mean)
# class1    gr1    gr2 
#   3.0    2.0    2.5
```